# How do I cut up a layer into several others?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs4

Basically I've got a picture of all 6 strings on a guitar, and each string is assigned to a separate layer.

I want to split these 6 layers into 120 layers by splitting along the 20 fret lines. I started by making a selection of each fret, and then 'layer by cut', but this will take too long. Can anyone give me a quicker way?

The reason I'm doing this is to apply a separate blending options set to each fret on each string, so if there's an easier way to do this, I'm happy with that.

Comment: grouping the layers? then cutting, then trying to ungroup them? or Hiding/disabling the background, so it is uneffected, and work with the top layers only.

Comment: You can't cut with multiple layers selected, even if they're part of a group.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found to do this was select the first string, select each fret, and then do 'layer by cut', and go to next layer with 'ctrl + {'. all the while recording the process as a photoshop 'action'. You then then play back this action on each string separately, so you only have to do the cutting process once.

I'd still like to see a solution for simply cutting multiple layers though.